# Visual Studio 2019 - Cannot publish a website to a local folder

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Dears,

I am using vs2019 enterprise version 16.11.2 and I am facing an issue while publishing a website to a local folder, I am getting index was outside the bounds of the array.
I tried to publish multiple website but with no hope.

it was working before but suddenly it doesn't publish anymore.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which array ?  (Please provide the code that you are trying to publish)

Comment: I am  trying to publish web application, each web application throws the same issue, i cannot create a publish profile although i can build the solution for both debug and release successfully